# Beamer - `uncover` within `only`

Tags: beamer

I've nest an `uncover` inside an `only` and it's not working as expected. The header of my document is :

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Warsaw}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds}
```

And the frame in question is the following :

```
\begin{frame}[label=review]
\frametitle{A review of the steps}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.4\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item \alert<1>{Supernova detection.}
\item \alert<2>{Spectroscopic confirmation.}
\item \alert<3,6>{Multi-band photometry.}
\item \alert<4,6>{Parameter extraction.}
\item \alert<5,6>{Hubble diagram fit.}
\end{enumerate}
\column{0.7\linewidth}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%[show background grid]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (step1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.18\linewidth]{figures/pedagogy/03D4ag-zoom1.png}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(step1.south east)},y={(step1.north west)}]
      \draw<1>[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%[show background grid]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (step2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.18\linewidth]{figures/guypres/1994D_spectrum.pdf}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(step2.south east)},y={(step2.north west)}]
      \draw<2>[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%[show background grid]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (step3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.18\linewidth]{figures/03D4ag-lc.png}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(step3.south east)},y={(step3.north west)}]
      \draw<3>[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%[show background grid]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (step4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.18\linewidth]{figures/03D4ag-lc-model.png}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(step4.south east)},y={(step4.north west)}]
      \draw<4>[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%[show background grid]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (step5) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.18\linewidth]{figures/pedagogy/hubblediagram.png}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(step5.south east)},y={(step5.north west)}]
      \draw<5>[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{columns}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\only<1>{
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figures/pedagogy/03D4ag-zoom1.png}
    \hspace{0.2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figures/pedagogy/03D4ag-zoom3.png}
  \end{center}
}
\only<2>{
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figures/guypres/1994D_spectrum.pdf}
  \end{center}
}
\only<3-4>{
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figures/03D4ag-lc.png}
    \hspace{0.2cm}
    \uncover<4>{
      \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figures/03D4ag-lc-model.png}
    }
  \end{center}
}
\only<5>{
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figures/pedagogy/hubblediagram.png}
  \end{center}
}
\end{overlayarea}

\end{frame}
```

The behavior I'm expecting is that 03D4ag-lc.png will be displayed on slide 3, and 03D4ag-lc-model.png will appear on slide 4, without displacing 03D4ag-lc.png. Instead, 03D4ag-lc-model.png seems to completely ignore the `uncover` command, and is present on both slides. Is this normal ? If so what is the proper way of accomplishing what I'm aiming for here ?

Comment: If I create a quick test document by adding `\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}\documentclass{beamer}\begin{document}\begin{frame}\begin{itemize}[<+->]\item Stuff \item More stuff\end{itemize}` before your code and `\end{frame}\end{document}` after it then all seems to be fine. Could you expand your demo to some code which shows the issue?

Comment: @JosephWright I've added the complete slide. Hope it's not too much of a mess for you. The `\uncover<4>` is what seems to be defective.

Comment: does adding `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` **inside** your `overlayarea` environment solve your problem?

Comment: @dcmst Yes it does... How did you figure that out ? Could you explain what's going on here in an answer ? I can guarantee you and upvote and answer confirmation if you do.

Comment: @ticster The `transparent` option doesn't work for images, only for text, so if you've seen this before it's not that hard to track down :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are setting the covered effect to `transparent` via the `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` macro.

As @JosephWright notes, the transparency does not work for imported images, so you got no covered effect at all when you tried to uncover an imported image with:

```
\uncover<4>{
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figures/03D4ag-lc-model.png}
}
```

To hide images you need to re-set the transparency effect using

```
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
```

I suggested to put the spec inside your `overlayarea` so that it does not override the first setting in the rest of the frame.

You may also want to chack section 17.6 of the Beamer manual.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now that you mention it, I did only notice this bug after having made several modifications to the slide, including changing the cover mode. I had just added so many things by then I didn't realize that's what did it.